# how to use capybara on your rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Basically i wanted to scrape a site, eg i want my app to go to google.com,  do a search then get the total number of results.

So I'd use capybara to do that - but it seems I can't get it to work inside my rails controllers.

So either i use capybara to scrape a site or you guys can suggest an easier way?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you could try with these 2 screencasts from railscasts, fairly simple.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri

http://railscasts.com/episodes/173-screen-scraping-with-scrapi